# While using navigation drawer, I cannot change ActionBar icons on the right

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

For my application, I have a navigation drawer and used the one available in Android Studio when you first create an app. I am trying to change the icon on the right side of the action bar which is currently 3 dots above each other. I have created a menu xml file with the icon, title, id and everything, and also whenever I inflate it, I use the correct menu xml file I created for it. I want to add a simple "+" icon up there and cannot figure it out.

Here is my menu xml file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/add_profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_new"
        android:title="@string/add_title"
        android:showAsAction="always"
    />
</menu>
```

And here is the onCreate method. My menu file is called menu_add_profiles.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_add_profiles, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Is there another step I need to take or can take to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Your current inflating the menu only if the navigation drawer is open..You need to remove this condition and all will work for you.Something like below should work.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_add_profiles, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }
```

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problem and found a solution:

Change `android:showAsAction="always"` to `app:showAsAction="always"` and add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`.

Here's my `menu.xml`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/action_add_dialog"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_24dp"
    android:title="@string/action_add"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:visible="true" />
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings_pref"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_applications_24dp"
    android:title="@string/action_add"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:visible="true"/>
```